# Display different Categories groups in custom breadcrumbs

Tags: categories

I have a custom list of breadcrumbs that two of the levels reference different Category Groups. I'm able to get the correct breadcrumb to display for the page that I'm on using `category.title`, but I need to display the correct category for the previous breadcrumb also.

I've made some progress and have managed to get it to display the first category in the group I want by using `{% set county = craft.categories.group('counties').first() %}` but I need it to display the category that I've attached to the page with a category field, and not just the first item in the category.

Here's the current code:

```
{% block breadcrumbs %}
    <div class="full-width breadcrumbs nav-breadcrumbs navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class='container'>
            <header class='scroll'>
                <span class='nav-item'><a href="/"><i class="icon-home"></i></a></span>
                <span class='nav-item'><a href="/developments">All Developments</a></span>
                {% set county = craft.categories.group('counties').first() %}
                <span class='nav-item'><a href="{{ county.url }}">{{ county.title }}</a></span>
                <span class='nav-item active'><a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}</a></span>
            </header>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to solve it. `<span class='nav-item'><a href="{{ category.counties.first().url }}">{{ category.counties.first().title }}</a></span>` did the trick.

Clearly I just needed to print the category field, although I'm not sure why it needs the `.first()` after `category.counties` to print it? But it works at least after days of struggling to find an answer.